# Trying assigning aDefaultGroupId

Tags: c++, windows-7, firefox-addon, xpcom

Firefox assigns a `defaultGroupId` using [this source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/widget/windows/WinTaskbar.cpp#265) in C++.

Via XPCOM I can get it like this:

```
Cc["@mozilla.org/windows-taskbar;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWinTaskbar).defaultGroupId;
```

I can also set it with the `nsIWinTaskbar` service but I have to do it every time I open a window.

So basically whenever a window opens it opens with the DEFAULT group id.

I want to change that `defaultGroupId`. Is this possible? My alternative is to set group id of each window as it opens, which is kind of intensive and I'd therefore like to avoid :(

Comment: proofed thanks. mobile keybaords man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `defaultGroupId` is not actually assigned. It is essentially a getter property which is recomputed each time you access it. *So you cannot re-assign it*.

You could override/proxy the whole service, but that won't work either, because the method is also called directly in some places, bypassing the alternate XPCOM implementation you'd provide. So you cannot *override* it.

You don't want to patch process memory, because that would be a hack so big it *will* blow up in your face, in a future version at the latest.

So no, you cannot override/re-assign the default.

Comment: Aw dang, any alternative to the `nsiWinTaskbar` `setGroupId` method? Because for that I have to use window mediator service to watch windows.

Comment: No, not that I know of (well, except of plain WinAPI with js-ctypes, which I would recommend against because that would likely break Firefox internals in some subtle ways)